# CMD doesn't work when starting as a .NET process

Tags: .net, process, cmd, f#, command-prompt

Trying to capture Windows command prompt output with the following F# code:

```
let cmd = new Process()
cmd.StartInfo.FileName <- "cmd.exe"
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute <- false 
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow <- true
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput <- true
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError <- true
cmd.Start() |> ignore

let input = cmd.StandardInput
let output = cmd.StandardOutput
let err = cmd.StandardError
input.AutoFlush <- true
input.Write("dir" + Environment.NewLine)
input.Write("exit" + Environment.NewLine)

cmd.WaitForExit()
if not cmd.HasExited then cmd.Kill()

input.Flush()
let result = output.ReadToEnd()
let error = err.ReadToEnd()
printfn "RESULT\n%s\nERROR\n%s" result error
input.Close()
output.Close()
err.Close()

cmd.Dispose()
```

results in...

```
RESULT
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp>﻿dir

C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp>exit

ERROR
'﻿dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

In fact the result is the same (`'{command}' is not recognized...`) for every other command, such as `cd..`, etc. that otherwise work properly from a manually started and typed command prompt.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Running the above code in Visual Studios 2013 works fine for me.  I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

Although still not clear why, using `.StartInfo.Arguments` works, but using `.StandardInput` to execute a command does not, e.g.

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments <- "/C dir"
```

solves the conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my Cronix project.
maybe you will find the answer there

https://github.com/aph5nt/cronix/blob/master/tests/Cronix.Tests/ServiceEnviroment.fs